# Time difference calculations considering the midnight time using r

Tags: r

I am working on a problem where I need to calculate the time difference in minutes. I have the time values in `hh:mm:ss` format in a column (more than 28,000 values).

I have been using the following function to calculate the time difference.

```
tdiff <- dt[dt, Time_Diff := c(abs(diff(as.numeric(Time))),0.30), Student_ID]
```

where `dt -->` is the ordered data table and
`0.30 --> 30` minutes assigned to the last activity of the student in a course.

This works, but it is not considering the midnight time.

Thanks to @niko for his help and this problem is solved, however the '30 minutes' that should be assigned to each student's last activity is still not done. Any help in this direction will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The expected output is described below

```
S_Id    Date            Time           Time_Diff      Time_Diff(minutes)
A       10/08/2018      23:49:00       00:01:00       1 minutes 
A       10/08/2018      23:50:00       00:09:00       9
A       10/08/2018      23:59:00       00:02:00       2
A       10/09/2018      00:01:00       00:09:00       9
A       10/09/2018      00:10:00       08:02:00       482
A       10/09/2018      08:12:00       04:08:00       248
A       10/09/2018      12:20:00       10:01:00       601
A       10/09/2018      22:21:00       01:35:00       95
A       10/09/2018      23:56:00       00:09:00       9
A       10/10/2018      00:05:00       00:05:00       5
A       10/10/2018      00:10:00       00:02:00       2
A       10/10/2018      00:12:00       00:30:00       30
B       10/08/2018      23:49:00       00:01:00       1
B       10/08/2018      23:50:00       00:09:00       9
B       10/08/2018      23:59:00       00:02:00       2
B       10/09/2018      00:01:00       00:09:00       9
B       10/09/2018      00:10:00       08:02:00       482
B       10/09/2018      08:12:00       04:08:00       248
B       10/09/2018      12:20:00       10:01:00       601
B       10/09/2018      22:21:00       01:35:00       95
B       10/09/2018      23:56:00       00:09:00       9
B       10/10/2018      00:05:00       00:05:00       5
B       10/10/2018      00:10:00       00:02:00       2
B       10/10/2018      00:12:00       00:30:00       30
C       10/08/2018      23:49:00       00:01:00       1
C       10/08/2018      23:50:00       00:09:00       9
C       10/08/2018      23:59:00       00:02:00       2
C       10/09/2018      00:01:00       00:09:00       9
C       10/09/2018      00:10:00       08:02:00       482
C       10/09/2018      08:12:00       04:08:00       248
C       10/09/2018      12:20:00       10:01:00       601
C       10/09/2018      22:21:00       01:35:00       95
C       10/09/2018      23:56:00       00:09:00       9
C       10/10/2018      00:05:00       00:05:00       5
C       10/10/2018      00:10:00       00:02:00       2
C       10/10/2018      00:12:00       00:30:00       30
```

Comment: put you datetime in POSIXct-format.. calculating differences then becomes easy. I assume you have a date-component next to the time?

Comment: Yes, there is a date column before time.

Comment: The link in the expected output has the details of the sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Wimpel, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: see niko's answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting `date` and `time` to `POSIXct`

```
# dt is your data frame
diff(as.POSIXct(paste(dt$Date, dt$Time), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')) # or '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

That should do the trick.

**Data**

```
dt <- structure(list(Date = c("10/08/2018", "10/08/2018", "10/08/2018", "10/09/2018", "10/09/2018", 
                              "10/09/2018", "10/09/2018", "10/09/2018", "10/09/2018", "10/10/2018", 
                              "10/10/2018", "10/10/2018"), 
                 Time = c("23:49:00", "23:50:00", "23:59:00", "00:01:00", "00:10:00", "08:12:00", 
                          "12:20:00", "22:21:00", "23:56:00", "00:05:00", "00:10:00", "00:12:00")), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: thank you for a quick response. However, I am getting the following error if I used your logic:

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @Javeed Add `format=` inside `as.POSIXct`. See the edit. (And make sure the format is correct - maybe I confused days and months).

Comment: @Javeed Do *all* your dates and times have the same format?

Comment: Yes, all the date and time values are in the same format

Comment: I am seeing these warnings now:

Warning messages:
1: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
3: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
4: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
5: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
6: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
7: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @Javeed I believe `R` cannot find your local timezone. Insinde `as.POSIXct`, add the argument `tz = 'GMT'`. This will set the timezone to `GMT` and the warning should disappear. You can also choose another timezone as well.

Comment: @Javeed I cannot reproduce that error, so I cannot help. I added the data I used so you can check.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Using the logic that you shared how can I add the 30 minutes to the last entry?
What I need in my project is the last activity of a student should be assigned as 30 minutes. Your thoughts on this?